# Why is my carousel not loading to my webpage?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am having trouble getting my carousel to load into my webpage.
I have played around with adding CSS height/width to the carousel div and even tried adding height to the contained img elements, but must be failing somewhere.
All help is much appreciated. Here's the notable code (cut from a larger document)...

IN MY HEAD:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

AT THE BOTTOM OF MY BODY:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

THE CAROUSEL:

```
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-right="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner" roll="listbox">
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.neptunus.co.uk/app/uploads/2019/05/evolution-pieterschelte-rotterdam-76997-1.jpg" alt="Temporary structures built on the Pioneering Spirit catamaran">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Pioneering Spirit</h3>
                                    <p>Weeks at sea produced thousands of square meters of temporary hospitality structures.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.eventindustrynews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Neptunus-Image-2.jpg" alt="Main structure for England's Rugby World Cup.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Rugby World Cup</h3>
                                    <p>Twickenham proves annual demand for White Rose Crew, but this year was special.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.neptunus.co.uk/app/uploads/2019/05/evolutioniii-thales-farnborough1.jpg" alt="A three story structure for Farnborough Airshow.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Thales</h3>
                                    <p>Our favourite biannual build of the worlds largest airshow.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/luxurylondon.co.uk-storage-bucket-001/images/articles-body/603/masterpiece-2019-london.jpg" alt="Masterpiece Arts Fair, Chelsea.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Masterpiece</h3>
                                    <p>We are proud to be an integral part of this incredible transformation year in, year out.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/62AF/production/_112536252_cdf_200420_cardiffhospital18.jpg" alt="Emergancy hospital built in the Pricipality Stadium.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Emergancy Covid-19 Field Hospital</h3>
                                    <p>Helping turn The Pricipality Stadium into Wales largest hospital in just 10 days.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check jquery cdn and check for the latest CDN.Using bootstrap given CDN will not work for you

Comment: Thanks, but it was simply the blunder of not setting any of the slides to "active".

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the minute I posted this.

I hadn't set any of the slides to "active".

Easy fix :)